# How to exclude a subfolder from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I'm using the plugin User Access Manager to restrict access to the folder uploads in a Wordpress site.
This folder is located at example.com/wp-content/uploads/.
The plugin has written this .htaccess in that folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?uamfiletype=attachment&uamgetfile=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In that folder (/wp-content/uploads/) there is also a folder called *wpsc* (/wp-content/uploads/wpsc/) with the files of the shop of the site.
Right now the .htaccess is working fine, but it's restricting the *wpsc* folder too. I need to add an exception so the *wpsc* folder can be accessed by everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Place a .htaccess file in the wpsc/ folder with the content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

This overrules the rewriterule in the .htaccess file in the parent folder

This works for the plugin **WP Photo Album Plus**, i.c. the ../wp-content/uploads/wppa/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the matched string with a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^wpsc/
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?uamfiletype=attachment&uamgetfile=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I tried other alternatives like !^wpsc, !^/wpsc/, !^/wp-content/uploads/wpsc and so on but they don't work either.

Comment: @Luis Herranz: Well, since the base path is `/`, you actually need to use `!^wp-content/uploads/wpsc/`.